# Producing indexes by two sets of indexes

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

I have two finite sets of integers $I$ and $J$ (possibly intersecting). Basically I want to index the cartesian product
$$
S = I \times J = \{(i,j)\}_{i\in I, j\in J}
$$
with natural numbers. In other words I want to build an injective function
$$
f : I\times J \to \mathbb{N}
$$
in a constructive and easy way, preferably with a direct formula (like $f(i,j) = |i|^{|j|}$, which doesn't work if for example both sets contain two natural numbers in common). 
I already have an "indirect" way: to order in $I\times J$ by the standard 
$$(i_1,j_1) << (i_2,j_2) \Leftrightarrow i_1<i_2 || (i_1=i_2 \&\& j_1<j_2)$$
and to assign $f(i,j) = max(max(I),max(J))+order(i,j)$.

Comment: You can index $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ and take the restriction to $I\times J$. There are $(p, q)\mapsto 2^p(2 q + 1)$ or $(p, q)\mapsto p + \frac{(p+q)(p+q+1)}{2}$.

Comment: Yeah, this actually works, thanks. It is easy to show that it is injection. Thank you.